# Difference between signed and unsigned division when the divisor is 2

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, bit-shift

Currently I am reading through the Intel 64-bit documentation, however I am confused by the pseudocode for the shift instructions.

The pseudocode states that

```
IF instruction is SAR
THEN
    DEST ← DEST / 2; (* Signed divide, rounding toward negative infinity *)
ELSE (* Instruction is SHR *)
    DEST ← DEST / 2 ; (* Unsigned divide *)
```

-Page 341 of vol 2

As the divisor is in both cases 2, shouldn't they always have the same result?

Comment: Not for numbers with the MSB set (sign-bit for signed, just another place value for unsigned).